# Удалить класс у элемента когда меню закроется

Tags: javascript

В проекте использую мобильное меню [mmenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/core/api.html).

Добавила иконку sandwitch с анимацией. Анимация происходит после добавления класса `on`, так:

```
var api = $('#my-menu').data('mmenu');
api.bind('closed', function(){
    $('.toggle-mnu').removeClass('on');
});

$(".mobile-mnu").click(function() {

    var mmAPI = $('#my-menu').data('mmenu');
    mmAPI.open();

    var thiss = $(this).find('.toggle-mnu');
    thiss.toggleClass("on");        
    return false;
});
```

Проблема в том, что после закрытия меню, класс `on` не удаляется. Как удалить класс `on` после закрытия меню?

**UPD**

Заменила `closed` на `closePanel` - но это не помогло.

**UPD**

возможно проблема в том, что не работает `bind` - тут:

`api.bind('closePanel', function() {...}`

Comment: а где по предоставленной ссылке было найдено событие `'closed'`?

Comment: Посмотри секцию: _Available API hooks_

Comment: мой код немного отличается от официального. мой код можно исправить чтобы работало?

Comment: Что значит твой код отличается от официального? Ты изменяла саму библиотеку _mmenu_?

Comment: нет, просто этот код из другого моего проекта, но там все работает ,и я не понимаю почему здесь не срабатывает

Comment: Еще раз: код не работает, потому что такого события нет в указанной библиотеке. Если это работает где-то еще, стоит проверить различия. Возможно там используется старая версия библиотеки, или вообще другая библиотека

Comment: Заменила closed на closePanel - но это не помогло.

Comment: сделай [mcve] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В версии [5.7.8](https://github.com/FrDH/jQuery.mmenu/releases/tag/v5.7.8) код работает корректно

Comment: То есть как я и сказал: в прошлом проекте _используется старая версия библиотеки_ :-)